# Zend controller Url in view

Tags: php, templates, zend-framework, url-routing, zend-router

I have a url

```
/module/controller/action/id/10
```

And what want to achieve is to generate the following url for an A tag inside a view partial

```
/module/controller
```

so basically I want to remove action name and extra id parameter

How can I do it using $this->url() inside the partial without having to pass any variables from a controller?

Thanks

EDIT:

Ok so I managed to write a piece of code that do it:

```
<?php
$module = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getModuleName();
$ctrl   = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getControllerName();
echo $this->url(array('controller' => $ctrl, 'module' => $module), null, true);
?>
```

but this is pretty ugly solution. Anyone any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There some solutions:

1) Get  module name & controller name from Controller and transmit to view ( u don`t like).

2) Do as you did ( ugly solution ).

3) Write custom [View Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html). Below example for you solution.

```
// view helper
class Custom_View_Helper_UrlCustom extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
  public function urlCustom()
  {
     $module = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getModuleName();
     $ctrl   = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getControllerName();
     return '/'.$module.'/'.$ctrl;
  }
}
```

Set path(s) to helper:
There 3 links how it in different ways to do ( I dont know how you want )

[Accessing and using Zend View Helpers from a common directory](http://www.mixedwaves.com/2010/03/accessing-and-using-zend-view-helpers-from-a-common-directory/)

SO:[Zend: Where/how can I register custom view helpers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194716/zend-where-how-can-i-register-custom-view-helpers)

SO:[Zend view helper configure path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156621/zend-view-helper-configure-pathworks-in-bootstrap-but-does-not-work-in-applicat)

```
// using in `view`
<?php echo $this->urlCustom(); ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set the `module` and `controller` name in the [Zend_Registry](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.registry.using.html), either from the Bootstrap or from any Plugins and can use it in the partial views.

```
<?=$this->url(array('controller' => Zend_Registry::get('controller'), 'module' => Zend_Registry::get('module')), null, true);?>
```